# python, using find to check for multiple values?

Tags: python

im trying to use find to check a string for multiple values, however im returning not found either when I compare both but found when I compare singular. can anyone see the issue in the code below?

```
R1prompt = 'SW1#'
if R1prompt.find(strR1) == -1 or R1prompt.find(strSW1) == -1:
   print 'not found either'
else  :  
    print 'found either'
if R1prompt.find(strSW1) == -1:    
    print 'not found S1'
else  :  
    print 'found S1'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`or` is true when either of its arguments are true. So your first condition prints "not found either" whenever *at least one* item is not found. You should use `and` instead.

Comment: im not sure i need and, the prompt could be one of two words, if either of those words are not found then continue

Answer (score 0):

That's because you should use

```
and
```

instead of

```
or
```

in

```
if R1prompt.find(strR1) == -1 or R1prompt.find(strSW1) == -1:
```

Comment: im not sure i need and, the prompt could be one of two words, if either of those words are not found then continue